# Android : Handling Logging (Lots of logging) properly - AsyncTask or Handler

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-handler

Note: I don't have any errors, I just want to somehow improve the handling of my logging.

I have an app that scrapes the internet, now I am attaching a javascript in the webview and it logs a lot (almost every 5-10 seconds) thru a Javascript interface that I exposed in the JS script. I know that the right thing to do is to handle my logging in the javascript that I'm using.

However, I would also like to know if which is the better way in handling it when I put in a background thread instead of just logging it right away in The UI thread.

What I currently do is I create a Handler inside a Singleton to avoid multiple instances of it.

```
public class SingletonHandler {

    private static SingletonHandler instance;

    private Handler logHandler;

    private SingletonHandler(){
        this.logHandler = createLogHandler();
    }

    public static SingletonHandler getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (SingletonHandler.class) {
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new SingletonHandler();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Handler createLogHandler() {
        HandlerThread logHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LogHandlerThread");
        logHandlerThread.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler(logHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String message = (String)msg.getData().get("message");
                String tag = (String)msg.getData().get("tag");
                String type = (String)msg.getData().get("type");

                Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(tag);
                if (type.equals(LogType.ERROR.getKey())) {                          
                    logger.error(message);
                } else if (type.equals(LogType.INFO.getKey())) {
                    logger.info(message);
                } else if (type.equals(LogType.WARN.getKey())) {
                    logger.warn(message);
                } else if (type.equals(LogType.DEBUG.getKey())){
                    logger.debug(message);
                } else {
                    logger.trace(message);
                }
            }
        };
        return handler;
    }


    public Handler getLogHandler(){
        return this.logHandler;
    }

}
```

And this my LogManager.

```
public class LogManager(){

    private static final Handler logHandler = SingletonHandler.getInstance().get

    public void logInfoMessage(String tag, String Message){
        if(MyConfig.isLoggingEnabled()){
            logMessage(tag, "INFO", message);
        }
    }

    public static void sendLogMessage(String type, String tag, String message) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(LOG_MESSAGE, message);
        bundle.putString(LOG_TAG, tag);
        bundle.putString(LOG_TYPE, type);

        Message messageToSend = logHandler.obtainMessage();
        messageToSend.setData(bundle);
        logHandler.sendMessage(messageToSend);
    }
}
```

When I turn off the logging, the performance improves drastically (30% - 40%).

> MyConfig.isLoggingEnabled()

Also, in my Handler, I was previously using

> logHandler.post(Runnable)

However, I was getting an OutOfMemory error so I decided to use the ***sendMessage(Message)*** instead.

Again, I will reduce the logging in my scripts, however I still need some of those logs I might reduce it up to 20%. I will still probably log every (10-20 seconds).

Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: Consider a logging library like Timber

Comment: I am currently using slf4j. I will consider it but again, I think it will somehow hit my performance regardless.

Comment: There are ["lower cost alternatives"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#arg1) to using a `Bundle`: *arg1* and *arg2* are `int` values (you should at least be able to map the `LogType` to a handful of integers, maybe even the *tag* (usually some identifier of a certain part of your app - I'm sure there is a finite number of them ),  and there also is *obj* (an `Object`) which could take the *message*. (cont)

Comment: (cont) I also heard that it's better for performance to use `int` over enums - don't know whether this is still valid with modern android versions. But it's another thing you could try.

Comment: @0X0nosugar it makes sense, perhaps I can create an Object or a HashMap that contains my values, would that be a better alternative than using the bundle?

Comment: For *type* you can use something like `static final int TYPE_ERROR = -1`, `static final int TYPE_INFO = 0`etc. For the tags, maybe you need a HashMap (or a `String` array where arg2 is the index?) and again, e.g. for coding convenience, maybe have the possible keys/ indices as `static final int TAG_WHATEVER = 42`)  All of this could be part of your `LogManager`

Comment: Avoid creating Objects, try to stick to primitive data types, and if you have to create an Object, try to do it once (as a field of some long-lived Object in your app) instead of as a local variable. For example `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` - if this means the Logger is created again and again then it's too expensive

Comment: Why are you doing all logging in the gui thread (snyc via post+handler)? I am directly using android-Log and slf4j in background threads without noticing any problems.

Comment: @k3b I have another Looper from a HandlerThread. I'm not using the main thread

Comment: @Aaron: from my experience you can do logging in every thread as long as you are not using gui-elements. no need to sendMessage/postMessage for logging